# Calculate Receiving Postfix Mailserver Successful Delivery vs. Failure

Tags: bash

I'm trying to calculate a rough percentage of how much email my mail server processes for successful delivery vs. how much it drops on the spot as email coming from misconfigured mail servers, spam, etc...

I first ran the following 2 commands in the /var/log/ directory (to catch entries in maillog as well as older maillogs that have been rotated out):

```
grep "dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)" * | wc -l
7814

grep "NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT" * | wc -l
13338
```

But then I thought that these entries might be picking up duplicates (especially the NOQUEUEs). So I ran the following slightly modified command to see how much of a discrepancy there might be.

```
grep "dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(" * | wc -l
8839
```

Looking at my maillog entries, I'm getting multiple NOQUEUE entries for delivery attempts. But I think that's because the sending mail server(s) sometimes attempt multiple deliveries. For example:

```
Aug 10 10:48:24 mail postfix/smtpd[7159]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[112.198.103.178]: 450 4.7.1 Client host rejected: cannot find your reverse hostname, [112.198.103.178]; from=<fqdbscjuvyae@geuzenhuis.be> to=<eddie@mydomain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<112.198.103.178>
Aug 10 10:48:24 mail postfix/smtpd[7159]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[112.198.103.178]: 454 4.7.1 <duncan@developco.freeserve.co.uk>: Relay access denied; from=<fqdbscjuvyae@geuzenhuis.be> to=<duncan@developco.freeserve.co.uk> proto=ESMTP helo=<112.198.103.178>
Aug 10 10:48:24 mail postfix/smtpd[7159]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[112.198.103.178]: 454 4.7.1 <djg@developdeploystrategy.co.uk>: Relay access denied; from=<fqdbscjuvyae@geuzenhuis.be> to=<djg@developdeploystrategy.co.uk> proto=ESMTP helo=<112.198.103.178>
Aug 10 10:48:24 mail postfix/smtpd[7159]: disconnect from unknown[112.198.103.178]
```

So I have 2 questions:

1. Should I be worried about catching duplicate entries with a grep of just `NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT`?
2. Is there a better method I should consider when filtering these log entries and coming up with the correct numbers?
3. How can I determine a unique line for each successful delivery. Looking at the difference between `grep "dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)" * | wc -l` and `grep "dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(" * | wc -l` we can tell there's a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Those seem to be separate delivery attempts, so should be counted as such.
2. Assuming this sort of thing must have been tackled already, I looked at the `munin` `postfix_mailstats` script how it's done there. That is a perl script, so the regexps are perl-compatible:

These are successful deliveries:

```
/ to=.*, status=sent /
```

These are rejects:

```
/postfix\/smtpd.*proxy-reject: \S+ (\S+)/
/postfix\/smtpd.*reject: \S+ \S+ \S+ (\S+)/
/postfix\/cleanup.* reject: (\S+)/
```

The captured part of the regexp (between brackets) is the reject code which indicates how the message has been rejected.

3. `delivered to maildir` is a local delivery, the `250 .* from MTA` is a remote delivery, i.e. two distinct types of delivery; so it's not strange you count different numbers of each.